# Eclipse Java - ApplicationEvent

Tags: java, eclipse, events

I am trying to update a substantial (>100,000 lines) application that was last worked on in 2008, using Eclipse Galileo and Java.  I downloaded and installed the lastest Eclipse/Java, and tried to "build" it.

Eclipse gives many errors which say
"ApplicationEvent cannot be resolved to a type"
(in addition to 1,080 warmings . . . )

Searching around I don't find anything on "ApplicationEvent".  Does anyone know what has happened with Eclipse/Java in the past 13 years?  Was "applicationEvent" replaced by something else?  Can anyone offer suggestions on how to proceed?

I have done almost no Java, but have a very strong background in C, as well
as some C# and C++.

Comment: this has very likely nothing to do with your choice of IDE. Where does 'ApplicationEvent' come from? Is it in the JDK? is it in one of your libraries? has it been deprecated/removed?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you provide an example of the code giving the error described?

Comment: What's the fully qualified name of ApplicationEvent?

Comment: Yes, exactly my question is where does ApplicationEvent come from - Here's some code

Comment: com.apple.eawt.Application application =  Application.getApplication();

     application.addApplicationListener(new com.apple.eawt.ApplicationAdapter() {
      public void handleAbout(ApplicationEvent ae) {
       new AboutDialog();  
       ae.setHandled(true);                 
      }
      public void handleOpenApplication(ApplicationEvent ae) {

      }
      public void handleOpenFile(ApplicationEvent ae) {

Comment: What about the Application.getApplication(); call ?

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationEvents are deprecated since 1.4. Use individual AppEvent listeners or handlers instead.
handleAbout and handleOpenApplication also been deprecated. Hence you are getting errors and warnings.

To get more information about ApplicationEvents and ApplicationListener Please refer

[http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~michaelm/7113349/7u4/2/jdk7u-osx/new/src/macosx/classes/com/apple/eawt/ApplicationListener.java.html](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Emichaelm/7113349/7u4/2/jdk7u-osx/new/src/macosx/classes/com/apple/eawt/ApplicationListener.java.html)

Hope you will get thread to proceed further.

Happy Coding!

Comment: You are most Welcome. Happy Coding!

Comment: What about the Application.getApplication(); call ?  Has that been substantially changed?  I am getting an error there that says "the method addApplicationListener is undefined for the type Application()"?  Can anyone refer me to documentation on the type "Application" ?  I can't find any, I think due to the problem that "Application" refers to so many other things . . .